# Calculating t if only the mean difference, N, and 95%CI are available

Tags: t-test

I'm looking to calculate a repeated measures t-test for a study that only reported the mean difference and the 95% confidence intervals. I also know the number of participants in each condition.

The info is as follows:

Mean difference = 27%
95% CI = [9%, 38%]
N = 15

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the variances assumed to be equal?

Comment: First problem, the 95% CI's are asymmetric about the mean $27-9=18$ and $38-27=11$, that is, assuming second problem, the 95% CI's are from the difference, are they?

Comment: You'll need to clarify how the CI was calculated.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 95% CI is from a Student's distribution difference then the [dependent paired-t test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Dependent_t-test_for_paired_samples) is

$$t = \frac{\overline{X}_D - \mu_0}{\frac{s_D}{\sqrt{n}}}\;.$$

The 
Student's-t inverse for $n-1=14$ degrees of freedom and a probability of $p=0.05$ is $t=2.144786688$, which is of slightly larger (magnitude) than the normal inverse single tail (to make 95% CI's) $p=0.025$ of $-1.959963985$ SD. Let us assume that the [95% CI is from a normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps), which is problematic since the mean minus the lower confidence interval is 18%, and the upper confidence interval minus the mean is only 11%, suggesting some skewness and non-normality.

**Case 1** Let us further assume that this is the 95% confidence interval of the difference distribution. That gives us a standard deviation of $\frac{38-9}{2\times1.959963985}\%=7.398095125\%$. Now, we would not want to divide by the Student's-t because that would reduce our estimate for the SD, and we need to be conservative.

That could be used to calculate a t statistic of 14.13479397
corresponding to a small $p<0.0001$. The probability is still likely to be small for minor changes to this calculation, but, we really still need to know what the confidence intervals represent.

**Case 2** The other possibility is that the 95% confidence interval are of the location of the mean, and if so we take half the 95% CI, or $\frac{38\%-9\%}{2}=14.5\%$ and multiply it by $\frac{\sqrt{15}}{1.959963985}$, giving us an SD of $28.65269921\%$. Then $t=\frac{\sqrt{15}\times27}{28.65269921}=3.649588109
$, and $p=0.003$ for 14 degrees of freedom from the Student's t distribution. Now since the CI are not symmetric about the mean, we really need to know how they were calculated. What paper or text did this come from, spill the beans, please?